# Как заполнить массив рандомными буквами и числами

Tags: c++, массивы, случайные-числа

Мне нужно заполнить двумерный массив рандомными цифрами и латинскими буквами. И если с числами и буквами отдельно проблем не возникает, то как сделать это вместе я совсем не понимаю. Каким образом можно заполнить массив рандомными цифрами и буквами одновременно?

Comment: Числами или цифрами?

Comment: цифрами, верно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно это?

```
const int N = 100;
char s[N];
for(int i = 0; i <N; ++i)
    s[i] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[rand()%36];
```

Comment: почти... мне нужно чтобы заполнялся двумерный массив, желательно с двухзначными цифрами тоже

Comment: @ULYANARSL А что, если сделать два вложенных цикла? А цифр двузначных не бывает...

Comment: Изложите **ТОЧНО**, что вам надо. Без точного ТЗ результат - ХЗ...

Comment: Если вдаться в подробности. Мне нужно узнать каким образом можно заполнить двузначный массив [10][10] рандомными буквами и цифрами

Comment: @ULYANARSL Цифрами, ага. Двузначными...

Comment: Числами... это не суть важно

Comment: Точно так же, как и в ответе, только два цикла, один вложен в другой...